# How to communicate through a headphone jack between arduino and a phone

Tags: android, iphone, bluetooth, arduino, zigbee

Is there anyway that I can take a receiver (arduino) plugged into a phone and have it send data from the receiver through the audio jack to the phone to execute commands on the phone such as make a call or send a text? In the event that the audio jack doesn't work, possibly the microusb then. I want to use zigbee or some other long range communication method to talk to the receiver that is plugged into the phone if its possible to bypass the receiver and do this directly with the phone then that would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Android devices can't implement Zigbee communication directly, so if you can change communication device (like Wifi or bluetooth) it would be better.
But if you want to use zigbee (an arduino is required then) I suggest 2 ways:

1. You could use a bluetooth module on the arduino board and communicate to android phone with that
2. You could implement a communication with the phone mic like in this project:
   [Android, Arduino, and the Headphone Jack Slideshare](http://www.slideshare.net/wolfpaulus/android-arduino-and-the-headphone-jack)

Good luck!

Comment: Yes i understand the phone its self cant communicate with zigbee but im looking for the long range that zigbee provides over bluetooth communication. If i were able to make a reciever that accepts zigbee such as an arduino with xbee shield would i then be able to convey the information i send to the arduino to send commands to the phone.

Comment: Ok, read the list in the answer above, i provided you 2 different implementation examples (arduino+bluetooth or arduino and microphone)